# writing a query for updating a table using another table's attributes by using a clause

Tags: mysql

I WANT TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addwinner AFTER INSERT ON bids
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
IF exists(select * from wins as LT where LT.item_index=NEW.item_index) THEN

SELECT item_index, MIN( bid_amount ) 
FROM update_winnerslist AS a1
WHERE a1.item_index =  NEW.item_index;
UPDATE wins SET email_id=NEW.emai_id, bid_amount=a1.bid_amount where wins.item_index=a1.item_index;

END IF;
END;
```

Basically what i want is to update a table using another table's tuple by comparing certain attributes.

Comment: How to use a different table's attributes to update a table's certain attributes based on a clause..i have tried the query above but ir doesnt work

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Are you getting errors?  If so, what are they?  Are you not getting the results you expected?  If so, what did you expect and what are you seeing instead?  It helps if you're more explicit.

Comment: i want to combine the 2 queries(SELECT and then UPDATE) written in bold into a single query

Comment: error::u have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html), when defining procedures/triggers/etc. that use `;` within their body to separate commands, you need to define an alternate delimiter in order that the `CREATE` command is interpreted as a single statement.

To `UPDATE` with the results of the `SELECT`, like you describe, you can do any of:

1. Save the result of the `SELECT` in a variable which you then use in the `UPDATE`:

   ```
   DELIMITER ;; -- or anything else you like

   CREATE TRIGGER addwinner AFTER INSERT ON bids FOR EACH ROW
     IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wins AS LT WHERE LT.item_index=NEW.item_index)
     THEN
       SELECT MIN(bid_amount) INTO @bid_amount
       FROM   update_winnerslist AS a1
       WHERE  a1.item_index = NEW.item_index;

       UPDATE wins
       SET    email_id=NEW.emai_id, bid_amount=@bid_amount
       WHERE  wins.item_index=a1.item_index;
     END IF;;  -- whatever command delimiter you chose above goes here

   DELIMITER ; -- reset to normal
   ```
2. Just use a subquery (so long as it doesn't reference the table you're updating):

   ```
   DELIMITER ;; -- or anything else you like

   CREATE TRIGGER addwinner AFTER INSERT ON bids FOR EACH ROW
     IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wins AS LT WHERE LT.item_index=NEW.item_index)
     THEN
       UPDATE wins
       SET    wins.email_id=NEW.emai_id, wins.bid_amount=(
         SELECT MIN(bid_amount)
         FROM update_winnerslist AS a1
         WHERE a1.item_index = NEW.item_index
       )
       WHERE  item_index = NEW.item_index
     END IF;;  -- whatever command delimiter you chose above goes here

   DELIMITER ; -- reset to normal
   ```
3. Or just join the tables:

   ```
   DELIMITER ;; -- or anything else you like

   CREATE TRIGGER addwinner AFTER INSERT ON bids FOR EACH ROW
     IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wins AS LT WHERE LT.item_index=NEW.item_index)
     THEN
       UPDATE wins JOIN update_winnerslist AS a1 USING (item_index)
       SET    wins.email_id=NEW.emai_id, wins.bid_amount=MIN(a1.bid_amount);
       WHERE  item_index = NEW.item_index
     END IF;;  -- whatever command delimiter you chose above goes here

   DELIMITER ; -- reset to normal
   ```

Comment: but i do not want my trigger to return anything..i do not actually want to use the two commands seperately. I want to actually SELECT a certain tuple(as a1) from my update_winnerlist view(the select statement returns a single tuple) and then use this tuple to update the **wins** table based on a certain clause (i.e. where wins.item_index=a1.item_index)